Would you say "settle on doing something", or is only "settle on something" correct?
Normally, gerunds are also nouns and you can say any of these, for example, "I like football", "I like coming to a football field to see my friends play" or "I like playing football".
However, I think I've come across some verbs which only go with normal nouns, not gerunds. One of them might be settle on. To be honest, I can't remember how that piece of information got into my head. Maybe I read it somewhere. So the question is: Do you use settle on with gerunds? For example:

I finally settled on taking my girlfriend with me to a foreign country.
 I finally settled on living with my girlfriend.

If the answer is no, I also wonder if there's any verb that is like what I described above.

Yes, you can settle on {doing something}. You can even settle on settling in Seattle.

Yes, you can use settled on with gerunds. Both of your examples are fine:

I finally settled on taking my girlfriend with me to a foreign country.
I finally settled on living with my girlfriend.

When you settle on something, you decide to do it. It implies that you had a choice between it and one or more alternatives that you considered.
